# Ploting given values in time windows (or time slots)

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot energy of a body in 20s time window. In first 20s window the energy is 1 unit, in the next 20s window energy is 4 units and in the third 20s window the energy is 9 units.

I have only one array containing energy values:

```
Energy=[1 4 9 ] ;
```

I have taken only 3 values for illustration only. Actually I am having 1024 values.

**How do I plot energy vs time graph as shown below?**

[image]

**This does not help:**

```
t=1:3
plot(t, Energy )
```

neither this one (which is wrong as the dimensions of t and Energy are not equal)

```
t=1:60
plot(t, Energy )
```

Finally I tried this one;

```
  Energy=[1 4 9 ] ; 

 n=0;

  for k=1:3

      for i=1:20

  Energy(i+n)=Energy(k);

        end 

      n=n+20;

  end 



t=1:60;
 plot(t,Energy  )
 xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Energy')
```

Which is giving wrong plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure you posted looks like a [stairstep plot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html); try

```
t = [0 20 40 60]; 
Energy = [1 4 9 4]; 
stairs(t, Energy)
```

From your plot I also see that you want a final bit of horizontal line that is equal to the last value of Energy. To do this, before you plot the data, you could do the following,

```
t = [t t(end)+20]; 
Energy = [Energy Energy(end)];
```

Comment: what should be the values of t ?